# When marker is supplied, does a request to list objects start with that key, or one after the key?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The documentation for AWS for Ruby has for [AWS::S3::Client#list_objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_objects-instance_method) has

> `:marker` (`String`) — Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket.

which I assume would mean that if you passed in `marker: 'foo/bar.baz'`, then the object with a key of `'foo/bar.baz'` would be included in the results.

However, the language-neutral documentation for listing objects [GET Bucket (List Objects)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) says (emphasis added)

> marker
>
> Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket. Amazon S3 returns object keys in alphabetical order, starting with key **after the marker** in order.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: None

Experimentation with actual Ruby code suggests the latter is correct, but what is the specified behaviour? Including, or excluding, the object with a key matching the value of `marker`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both the ruby and the API documentation begin with the same phrase:

> Specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket.

However, this is where S3 starts its *search*, not it's listing.

Results actually begin with the next object key after the marker.

(This is also true If the key designated by the marker doesn't actually exist -- results begin with the next key).

Comment: FYI if you happen to specify a version-id-marker and leave key-marker blank (not really valid?) like "?delimiter=&max-keys=1&prefix=&versions=&key-marker=&version-id-marker=null" it skips the first key in the xml results. Removing "&version=id-marker=null" brings it back.